# Populating many controls from the database (architecture and performance concerns)

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, architecture, webforms

So I have this page that collections a lot of information to create a little complicated object. so I collect all the related details together in a div and I have like 7 Divs, and I populate like 20 controls (DropDownListss, CheckBoxLists, Repeaters, etc).

Now I'm just creating methods to be called on Click and Page_Load events.
each population process is done separately.

The code is a hassle and I don't except the performance to be good either, because I know that a lot of connections/trips to the database is not good for performance and the load on the database.

so how can I put this functionality in a better design and a better performance, any help here =) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not load all this data in Page_Load?  Then once in memory (whether in objects, data readers, or data sets), populate your controls?

Comment: Populate a DropDownList items from the a database table .. and how to do that all at once ?

Comment: We store commonly used dropdown list values in Cache, so there's no overhead for populating them.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get what you want to say or how exactly do you store them in cache ? .. and what happens if those values have changed in the database at anytime! .. how are my controls going to be populated !?

Comment: If the values constantly change then you need to pull them each time.  But still, 20 controls is not very much.

Comment: my point is even If the values doesn't change frequently, and I stored them in Cache (which I really have no idea how to do that!). In the end they will have to change one day, right ? how can I detect that they've changed ?

Comment: Your best bet is to stop worrying about performance now and just write the page.  If the performance is poor, come back and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a slightly philosophical question. As far as page perf. goes you shouldn't see a problem with only 20 controls. However, you have two key bottlenecks:

**1) Get from database**
You need to try and get all of the data from the database at once. Of course that's not always possible but it will save you a couple roundtrips. You can also cache that object for the current request.

**2) Save**
if you write to db on each change event on postback, it will take unnecessarily long. I'd suggest you crete a `Model` property that gets the model from the db and each change handler changes that model. Once the postbacks have all fired (I can't remember the best event now, but I think `Page_Load` is ok) write that model to the database in one single commit.

As far as performance goes, this is probably the least effort for maximum gain. You can also load controls with Ajax to make seem faster but it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Also, make sure you cache dropdown field values for as long as possible. :-) using a repository pattern here saves you a looooot of effort.

Comment: Ok, about the saving. I'm persisting all the fields data so at the end I create an object and load all the data in the controls to it and then send this object to the database. about the first point I have two questions. 1)how to do so "You can also cache that object for the current request." 2) can you provide me with a sample for inserting/retrieving from multiplate tables at once and not using storedprocudes please =)

Comment: I really need to learn about that advanced stuff, the repository and the NH hibernate! .. I hear they are very good solutions for both architecture and performance but I can't risk my not meeting the dead line of my current projects! .. so If you have a good book or article that go to the point and you think it's good, I'd be happy if you could recommend any :)

Comment: The example would be easier to provide if you elaborate a bit on your db structure and what you want to display. Unless the underlying model is really complex I'm sure it's nothing a few joins couldn't handle :) I'll look at my bookmarks for a few good resources.

Comment: It's really a lot of tables .. but can't I just use one connection, open it, Execute all the commands and then close the connection ?

Comment: You can, and it's quite efficient. The question is, could you perhaps make it even better? If you are, for example, getting values of drop down lists (from related tables), you can shave off a lot of time.

Comment: They are related to the main item .. for example I'm having this page to collect info to create an object of type "Item" .. I load into my lists the tables "Item_Brands" and "Item_Properties". I'm not sure If I can call that related in my situation .. what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate has very nice feature called [NHibernate Futures](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures) (but not all databases are supported). You could also get another benefits from it such as caching out of the box, batching write queries and so on. So I recommend to consider this option.

BTW, do you really need all this information at the same time on the screen? You could split your UI layer and create, for example, wizard.

Comment: Actually I'm creating kind of a custom wizard and no I don't need them all at the same time but some controls that I need to populate are repeaters and I need those to be bound on an earlier handler than Page_Load. like Page_Init or sth! and about the NHibernate thing I don't understand it quite alright, but again I don't get the function or how to use those advanced tools at all! .. so if you can provide me with some articles or guides about them that don't waste time and get straight to the point, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: About what if I need to populate them all at once or not. I wasn't sure whether to find a way to create an Object and on each page I fill the properties of this Object and keep passing this Object through the PostBacks, or populate everything on an event like Page_Init and let the ViewState for all the controls to be true so I keep all the controls' values and load them into the object at once. I knew how to do the 2nd choice so I went for it :D and that's why I can't populate the next div in a click event or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the SQL queries yourself, you can combine most queries so that you only need one query per table.

E.g. you might have table `dropdown_choices`, which has `dropdown_id` and `choice` columns.

You could SELECT all the data that concerns you and then split it up in your code.

```
SELECT * FROM dropdown_choices WHERE dropdown_id IN (1, 2, 3, 10, ...);
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm retrieving from different tables

Comment: You could try spawning multiple threads for querying different things at the same time.

Comment: ohh threads! =) .. I'm not sure that I want to get into this mess! .. I'm just thinking for the performance side that I could use some kind of code to insert/retrieve all the data at once, like a joined query or using the same SqlConnection without closing it for more all the commands!